# Using Azure as database for asp.net mvc4 project

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, cloud

I'v an mvc project which is using the built-in SQL Server database. Now I want to use Azure cloud as a database to store the files. Is there a simple way to connect the project to Azure, so it uses the cloud instead of the built-in database?

Comment: Just change the connection string in web.config. That should do it.

Comment: It's a web application, do I have to convert it or something?

Comment: Nope. Should work as is AFAIK.

Comment: Cause I found this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh420322.aspx and it says something about converting?

Comment: Oh. This is when you want to deploy your application as Cloud Service. However you can simply deploy your application as Azure Website and no conversion will be required. You can simply select your web application in Visual Studio, right click --> Publish and it will be published as an Azure Website.

Comment: So if I only want to use the Azure cloud as a database, I don't need to follow this steps? All I need to do is change the connection string? Btw, sorry if I'm asking noob question, I'm new to this.

Comment: No worries on questions. You gotta start someplace :). To answer your question, Yes, just change the connection string and you should be good to go. However please understand that SQL Databases are by default not open to any IP address. In order for your web application to access the data in SQL database, you will have to configure firewall rules to allow your web application's IP address (in case the code is running locally, then your local computer's IP Address). But other than that, no changes should be required. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The question is little bit confusing:

If the web application (Mvc project you have) is already hosted somewhere and you want to continue with that but only replace the SQL Server with cloud version. Then all you need to do is create (pay for) an instance 'Azure SQL Server' and just change the connection string in web.config of the application.

Now if you also want to host the web application in azure then besides above you also need to create an 'Azure Website' and publish the code of your Mvc project there. It is actually very simple and will involve below steps:

- Create an 'Azure Website' on [azure portal](http://www.windowsazure.com)
- Download Publish
  Profile
- Using Visual Studio Publish feature, deploy the application